# Too many DML statements while sending an email

Tags: soql

In my class I am simply calling sendmail on a listof Email IDS, mean I am not performing any DML, but I am getting TOO MANY DML Exception. On observing the log I found call to a method "AIP_Extension_DTNotifyNow.__sfdc_docTrack()" . So I feel this method is doing something which is causing this DML exception.

Please let me know where and how can i find this method, or let me know any other possible reason for this error.

Please find the code below.

```
public pageReference sendEmail(){
  try{
  if(isValidDocument()){
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstSingleEmailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Description, Name, TemplateType FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'AIP Single DT Email Notification' limit 1];

    for(Id contactId : contactIds){
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      email.setTemplateId(template.Id);
      email.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
      email.setWhatId(docTrack.Id);
      email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
      lstSingleEmailMessages.add(email);
    }

    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] result = Messaging.sendEmail(lstSingleEmailMessages); 

    if(result[0].isSuccess()){
      emailSentAt = Datetime.now();
      isSuccess = true;

      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Email has been sent successfully.'));
    }
    else{
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error while sending email :'+result[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage())); 
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception e){            
   system.assert(false,contactIds+'>>>'+e.getMessage()+'>>'+e.getStackTraceString());
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use?

Comment: Yes Lex, Please find below the code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there may be a trigger running that you are unaware of and that is probably not properly bulkified. Since you are sending emails attached to an object docTrack I would look for triggers on whatever object that represents. I would start by looking for the class `AIP_Extension_DTNotifyNow` since it has the method causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike, But as per the code, I do not see any DML Happening, So what could initiate a trigger? also on seeing logs I can find AIP_Extension_DTNotifyNow.__sfdc_docTrack() this line mentioned,I do not know where to look for __sfdc_docTrack() method if you know of, is it related to Audit Trails or something?

Comment: There could be a trigger set to run whenever a new email attached to the object. Given the class name it's probably from an installed package, so I would go to Setup | Develop | Triggers and see what's in there.